# Working with hashes in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, hash

My apologizes if this has been covered before; I searched and searched but I did not find an answer...

I have the following hash:

```
input = '{"names":[{"name":"a1","id":1},{"name":"b2","id":2}]}'
```

I'd like to extract and display the values- one per line.  When I run it from rails console, I get the correct results:

```
    >> r1 = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(input)
    => {"names"=>[{"name"=>"a1", "id"=>1}, {"name"=>"b2", "id"=>2}]}
    >> r1["names"].each do |x|
    ?> puts "#{x["name"]}"
    >> end
    a1
    b2
    => [{"name"=>"a1", "id"=>1}, {"name"=>"b2", "id"=>2}]
```

THe question is how do I replicate this behavior in my rails application?  I tried the following method, but only one value is return in the browser:

```
    module PageHelper
        def testcall()
        input = '{"names":[{"name":"a1","id":1},{"name":"b2","id":2}]}'
        r1 = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(input)
        r1["names"].each do |a|
            return "Name: #{a["name"]}\n"
        end
   end
```

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return`ing terminates the loop after the first element. Try appending the output to a string (including newlines `\n` in-between) in the loop, and then return that string after the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your asisstance! I also had to use <br> instead of \n and simpleformat to display it in the browser correctly after appending the output to a string.

Answer (score 0):

As @Irfy said, this is happening because of `return` statement. Following code works,

```
  module PageHelper
    def testcall()
      input = '{"names":[{"name":"a1","id":1},{"name":"b2","id":2}]}'
      r1 = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(input)
      r1["names"].map{|hash| hash["name"]}
    end
  end
```